# inverse of quadratic matrix form

Tags: matrices, inverse

I have an expression of the form:

$ACA′$

where C is an invertible, symmetric and positive definite matrix. I'm trying to figure out if the expression above is invertible (or what additional properties C would need to have). The C matrix is $n$x$n$ and the A matrix is $k$x$n$ ($k<n$). Every row of A has exactly one entry =1 and one entry =-1.

Any help, especially something pointing to a theorem, would be greatly appreciated (does A need to be of full row rank?).

Comment: are the other entries in $A$ all zero?

Comment: yes, only 2 non zereo entries per row, all else are 0

Comment: I deleted my comment. I write everything as $B^T H B$ and that is how I think, so i got turned around. If it is the rectangular matrix on the right that has columns with a 1 and a $-1$ otherwise 0, it depends on the rank. If it has full rank, which would be $k,$ it ought to work out, partly because you can write $C = G G^T,$ for example Cholesky form. And i believe we have had this question before.

Comment: Right, so then you are asking about $G^T A^T v,$ where $v$ is a nonzero column vector with $k$ entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ones and minus ones are not relevant since they occur as rows in $A$ but as columns in $A^T.$

I am going to write $B = A^T.$  As $C$ is symmetric positive definite, I am also going to write, for example by a Cholesky decomposition, as 
$$ C = H^T H.  $$ So, your expression becomes $$  B^T H^T H B,  $$ where $B$ has maximal rank, that being $k < n.$

Finally, I take a column vector $v \neq 0$ with $k$ entries. As the row rank and column rank of $B$ are the same, we find $Bv \neq 0. $ As $H$ is nonsingular, $HBv \neq 0.$ The dot product $(HBv) \cdot (HBv) \neq 0.$ So,
$$  v^T B^T H^T H B v \neq 0.  $$ In particular,
$$   B^T H^T H B v \neq 0.  $$ So,
$$   B^T H^T H B   $$ is square and nonsingular and therefore invertible; it is also symmetric positive definite.

If your matrix $A$ has less than maximal rank, you get a singular result instead.

Comment: @evgeny, my $H$ is nonsingular and therefore irrelevant. With your severe restrictions on $B= A^T$ it is very easy to have rank smaller than the number of columns, your $k.$ If I were you, I would test the behavior of the final square matrix on a vector with all entries $1,$ just in case.

Comment: My A is this way because it's an incidence matrix for a transmission network (where k is a subset of all the lines) so as long as I don't have any parallel lines, I believe the A will be of max rank.  I don't think my subset will ever have parallel lines but I'll need to be careful here.  Thanks again