# Is there a closed form expression for $(A^T\Sigma A)^{-1}$ when $A$ is not square?

Tags: matrices, inverse

I need to find the inverse of the matrix $A^T\Sigma A$.

Matrix $A$ has dimensions $5\times 2$. Matrix $\Sigma$ has dimensions $5\times 5$, and it is symmetric and positive-definite.

I need to express the inverse in the way like "$A^{-1} \Sigma^{-1}A^{{-1}^T}$", but $A$ is not a square matrix.

---

**Some more context**: The matrix $A$ is unknown, while $\Sigma$ is known.   I just need the general expression for that inverse, maybe involving some trace operators or something else.  I understand that it is possible to write the matrices, expicitly multiply them (in symbolic form) to get the giant expression, and then explicitly inverse the matrix. But maybe there is an expression in more closed form?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  As you point out, the reversing product order of inverses does not make sense since $A$ is not invertible (or even square).  Overall you ask to invert a $2\times 2$ matrix, which is easily done once you've multiplied out $A^T \Sigma A$.  Alternative approaches will be useful only as there is some more specific context.

Comment: There is the specific context there. Matrix A is unknown, $\Sigma$ is known. It would be long to explain all)

Comment: In fact I need not to calculate this inverse many times.

Comment: This expression is a part of larger expression which behaviour I am researching.

Comment: Well, sorry for little details.

Comment: It is very long to explain all the process.

Comment: The question arised from data analysis problem. I just need the general expression for that inverse. Maybe involving some trace operators or something else.

Comment: I understand that it is possible to write that matrices, expicitly multiply them (in symbolic form) to get the giant expression, and then explicitly inverse the matrix. But maybe there is an expression in more closed from? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for correction))

Comment: Suppose that $\Sigma = I$ is the identity matrix.  What is it that you want to know about the inverse of (in this case) $A^T A$ where $A$ is a $5\times 2$ matrix?  Of course we can write out this inverse in terms of the two columns of $A$.  Does that help you?

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate: [inverse of quadratic matrix form](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646738/inverse-of-quadratic-matrix-form]

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But there is no answer there.
Now I can formulate the problem exactly: I need to represent that inverse matrix (it is symmetric) as product $K^T K$ (K is 2*2 matrix). Thus I need to find how the matrix K is expressed via A and $\Sigma$.