# Relate the inverse of $U^\top A^{-1} U$ to $A$

Tags: matrices, inverse

Let $A$ be $N\times N$ symmetric positive definite, and let $U$ be $N\times (N-1)$ with full column rank, i.e. $U^\top U$ invertible. $U^\top A^{-1} U$ is invertible according to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646738/inverse-of-quadratic-matrix-form?rq=1), but is there any way to relate $(U^\top A^{-1} U)^{-1}$ to $A$ ? I tried the Sherman-Morrison formula, but I did not manage there.

Comment: Just because $U^TU$ and $A$ are invertible doesn't mean $U^TAU$ is. Are you assuming that it is the case?

Comment: yes we have to assume this. I'll update the post, tx!

Comment: One of the few rules I know to open up inverses with tall dimensions inside is $(X Y)^+ = (X^+ X Y)^+ (X Y Y^+)^+$, where $(\cdot)^+$ denotes the pseudo-inverse. I'm not very optimistic it will help you much but you could try (apply it twice).